# How to insert a character at a certain position in a number without converting it into a string?

Tags: javascript

I have to insert "/" between 2020 and 0001 in the number 20200001. I know how to do it by converting the number to string, but I am unable to do it by not converting it.

Comment: This makes no sense. Numbers _can not_ have “characters” like `/` in them. You want a string, whether you know it or not.

Comment: Adding "/" to a number will itself make it a string

Answer (score 2):

If you don't convert it to string, it just a number and the "/"is not a number so u need to convert it to a string.

please check this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp

```
function fortmat(date, format) {
    return date.toString().replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, `$1${format}$2${format}$3`)
}

console.log(fortmat(20200001, "/"));
```

This function helps you to convert the Date to another format.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can't have a "/" in a number. If this is a date you could convert it to a date with the "/" as a delimiter.

Here you can learn more about dates in Javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: Yes, its supposed to be a date. Thanks

Comment: Is this number always the same?

Comment: PS: A Date can't have 0 Months, the smallest date in 2020 is "20200101" --> "01.01.2020"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a symbol of any kind outside the numeric spectrum inside a number...

Imagine if you were a calculator and a student wanted you to substract the word banana from 400.

That doesn't make sense.

If you need two separate numbers, then store them in a sepatrate variable.

Comment: in base 35 this is well defined and its solution is banabu

Comment: uh... am I supposed to know what ur talking about..? 0.o

Comment: check this ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system -> then `banana_35 - 400_10 = banabu_35` there is a chance a student actually want to do this ;)